# Finding out which cciss disk is what /dev/sdX disk (smartmontools & cciss raid controller)

Tags: hp, hardware, hard-drive, hardware-raid, smart

I have a HP server, which has a hardware RAID array (that mostly isn't being used for raiding, the disks are just passed through to the Linux OS). I have 6 SSD disks. 2 are riad mirrored together by the array, the other 4 are exposed to the OS. One of the 4 is broken (by using dd, I was able to see that it was `/dev/sdd`. `/dev/sd{b,c,e}` all work fine).

I want to find out the serial number of `/dev/sdd`, so that when someone goes into the server room, they know the broken disk and can remove it. Usually `lshw`/`smartctrl`/etc can tell you that. But since there's a raid controller, all report the same serial number. But [smartmontools can read into the raid controller](http://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Supported_RAID-Controllers) with the `-d cciss,X /dev/sdY`:

```
smartctl -i -d cciss,1 /dev/sdd
```

But only the `cciss,X` in that matters, not the `sdY`. Running `cciss,0` on `sdb`, `sdc`, `sdd` or `sde` gives the same results. But running `cciss,1` on `sdb` gives different results from `cciss,0` on `sdb`.

How can I figure out which "cciss number" is used by `/dev/sdd`?

This is on Ubuntu Linux 14.04. There is no `/dev/cciss/*` files.

**Update**: It's a HP ProLiant SE316M1R2 which was refered to as a "160".

*(One answer might be to run a standard smart test on all cciss disks, and find which one is broken, but I tried to call a `-t short` and `-t long` on all cciss from 0-5 and all them except `cciss,0` and `,1` acted as if there had never been a test run on them.)*

Comment: What server model is this?

Comment: @ewwhite I've updated question with the server model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow...

*(there are special tools available for HP systems)*

Install the [`hpssacli`](http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/repo/mcp/pool/non-free/hpssacli-2.0-16.0_amd64.deb) tool:

And then look at the output of the `hpssacli ctrl all show config` command:

```
# hpssacli ctrl all show config

Smart Array P410i in Slot 0 (Embedded)    (sn: 50123456789ABCDE)

   array A (SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)


      logicaldrive 1 (838.1 GB, RAID 1+0, OK)

      physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:5 (port 2I:box 1:bay 5, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:6 (port 2I:box 1:bay 6, SAS, 300 GB, OK)

   SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model  SRC 8x6G) 250 (WWID: 50123456789ABCED)
```

---

Note: running `hpssacli ctrl all show config detail` will provide even more information...

Answer (score 0):

From some point in smartmontools, it became possible to view the status of disks in HBA mode with an HP controller. Here is the ticket and commit: https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/1472 https://www.smartmontools.org/changeset/5216

smartmontools version 7.3-1 on Ubuntu 22.10 gets SMART information from disks in HBA mode. This is a simple package, I think that it is not difficult to compile it for other systems.

Why did I need to monitor the status of disks through smartmontools when there are utilities from HP: these disks are used in the CEPH file system and the CEPH manager can monitor disks and send alerts about problems. Unfortunately CEPH can only do "smartctl -x --json=o <dev_name>".

Addition: before I found this ticket, I tried to link information from the system. I tried to map cciss,0 to /dev/sda ...

```
# ls /sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:*:0/block
'/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:1:0/block':
sda

'/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:2:0/block':
sdb

'/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:3:0/block':
sdc

'/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:4:0/block':
sdd

'/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:5:0/block':
sde

'/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:6:0/block':
sdf

# ls /sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:*:0/scsi_generic
'/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:0:0/scsi_generic':
sg0

'/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:1:0/scsi_generic':
sg1

'/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:2:0/scsi_generic':
sg2

'/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:3:0/scsi_generic':
sg3

'/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:4:0/scsi_generic':
sg4

'/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:5:0/scsi_generic':
sg5

'/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:6:0/scsi_generic':
sg6

'/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:7:0/scsi_generic':
sg7
```

then I would write a wrapper script that takes the device name as input in the form "/dev/sda", sets a correspondence between "/dev/sda", "/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:1:0/ ", "/dev/sg1" and executes "smartctl /dev/sg1"